# How to remove an uiview from parents view?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have an activity indicator which I display before a long running process.
After this process i simply try to remove that indicator again.

I am not able to. Indicator is showing up but then stays forever on my screen, even I remove it in the main thread.

Can someone help me ?

Code:

```
// Activity Indicator Variables
var messageFrame = UIView()
var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
var strLabel = UILabel()

// in viewdidappear
showprogressIndicator("Please Wait", true)
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    sleep(2); // LONG RUNNING TASK
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        for subview in self.messageFrame.subviews {
            subview.removeFromSuperview();

        }

        self.messageFrame.removeFromSuperview()
        //self.saveButton.enabled = true
    }
}



func showprogressIndicator(msg:String, _ indicator:Bool ) {
    var strLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
    strLabel.text = msg
    strLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var messageFrame = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.midX - 90, y: view.frame.midY - 25 , width: 180, height: 50))
    messageFrame.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    messageFrame.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.7)
    if indicator {
        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.White)
        activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        messageFrame.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    }
    messageFrame.addSubview(strLabel)
    view.addSubview(messageFrame)
    //self.messageFrame.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: You have never initialized `self.messageFrame`, or assigned anything to it. How you can expect it to be removed from the superview?

Comment: I am assigning other views to the messageFrame in the mehod showprogressIndicator ? I mean at least I see the messageframe on my screen displaying "Please wait" with an Indicator. My problem is howto remove it.

Comment: Please, read your code carefully (better twice!).

Comment: Is it a copy pasted code? Where are you running this from?

Comment: I can't see it. I mean I create the view with "var messageFrame = UIView" and I add a subview with messageFrame.addSubview(activityIndicator). Whats wrong with it ?

Comment: I am running this in my App. And I see the Indicator.

Comment: Just change `//self.messageFrame.removeFromSuperview()` to `self.messageFrame = messageFrame`, and it will work. You are not even trying to understand the previous comments.

Comment: You'd better remove the question altogether, it doesn't give any value to others. Voting to close.

Comment: Right. You are right. And You also are right with looking into it twice. Sorry for wasting the time. I didn't see my mistake. Thats embarrassing :-)

Comment: Its simply a stupid question, because its because of a simply failure of the questioner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with you code is that you are adding a different object(`var messageFrame`) to `self.view` while showing the progress indicator but when it is the turn to remove it, you are removing an entirely different object(`self.messageFrame`).
To resolve this, remove the local declaration from within your `showprogressIndicator` method and directly assign the allocated object to `self.messageFrame`.

```
self.messageFrame = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.midX - 90, y: view.frame.midY - 25 , width: 180, height: 50))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry for wasting your time. It was a simple failure of my. Shall I delete this stupid question ?

Comment: You should actually. It doesn't add any value to site. It is very simple mistake on your part which you could have identified anyway.

Comment: Right I marked for close, because I can't delete when there are answers.

Answer (score 2):

There are several errors in your codes. Sleep() is not a func to delay a certain part of execution. Please take a look of revised version and have it for reference.

```
    var messageFrame: UIView!

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        showprogressIndicator("Please Wait", true)
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
            ), dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                for subview in self.messageFrame.subviews {
                    subview.removeFromSuperview();
                }
                self.messageFrame.removeFromSuperview()
        })
    }

    func showprogressIndicator(msg:String, _ indicator:Bool ) {
        let strLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
        strLabel.text = msg
        strLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        messageFrame = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.midX - 90, y: view.frame.midY - 25 , width: 180, height: 50))
        messageFrame.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        messageFrame.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.7)
        if indicator {
            let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.White)
            activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
            activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            messageFrame.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        }
        messageFrame.addSubview(strLabel)
        view.addSubview(messageFrame)
    }
```